# Variant of read-regexp that shows matching string candidates upon TAB

Tags: regular-expressions, completion, completing-read

I'm looking for an extension of read-regexp, that given an additional parameter of completion candidates, shows the matching subset of these candidates in the minibuffer, when tab is pressed. Similar to how `find-file *.el TAB` shows list of files that match a path wildcard. One solution is to modify `read-regexp` to take an optional list of possible completions instead of the value of `(read-regexp-suggestions)`.